Can I solve this equation without looping for each value of x and y?

Given 2 positive integers c and n, find any 2 positive integer answers for x and y that satisfy the following equation: √x + √y = √z where z = c²n.
Input
The first line of the input contains a single integer t (1≤t≤105), the number of test cases. The first and only line of each test case consists of 2 space-separated integers c and n (4≤c²n≤1018, 2≤c≤109, 1≤n≤109)
Output
For each test case output 2 space-separated positive integers x and y, the answer to the equation.
If there are multiple answers, print any.

I tried to make y = n, and then calculate x by quadratic analysis:
√x + √y = c*√n
=> x + 2√y√x + y = c²n
=> x + 2√y√x + y - c²n =0
Then, I calculated x by quadratic analysis:
=> x = (-b + √(b² - 4ac))/2a
Note: the time limit for this problem is 1.3 seconds, which means in the worst case I shouldn't use more than 1010 or 1011 steps.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, n , c;
    double x, num1, num2;

    cin >> t;

    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        cin >> c >> n;

        num1 = (double)n - (pow(c, 2)*n);
        num2 = (double) ((-2*sqrt(n))+sqrt((4*n)-(4*num1)))/2;

        cout << (double)pow(num2 , 2) << ' ' << n;
    }
}

I get the wrong answer but I don't know what's wrong.

Your main problem is mixing floating point and integer math. e.g. don't use std::pow for this. And your solution doesn't have to call std::sqrt the equality still holds for the squares of the numbers (do not do more work than you have to)

Watch this video Floating Point Numbers - Computerphile so you can better understand why

The posted code doesn't have a loop for each case, and thus seems to answer your question.

can I use equation which calculate integer values only not float or double values

The equation √x + √y = √z is kind of like a reverse Pythagoras (x² + y² = z²). Perhaps this could help you find a suitable solution?

By the way, it's rather easy to rewrite the equation to get either x or y, but not both. There will almost always be multiple values of x and y that satisfy the equation. By the way, c² * n feels like a red herring, unless there's a mathematical property making the equation easier to solve. Any anyway, this feels more like a math problem than a programming problem... Once the math is solved, it should be rather straightforward to translate it into code (which seems to be the case with too many so-called "competition" or "judge" or "homework" sites).

#include <iostream>

void solve_test_case() {
    long long c, n;
    std::cin >> c >> n;
    
    // Strategy: Let's make x = (c-1)*(c-1)*n and y = n
    // This ensures √x + √y = c√n
    long long x = (c-1)*(c-1)*n;
    long long y = n;
    
    std::cout << x << " " << y << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        solve_test_case();
    }
    return 0;
} 


This is a good solution! Actually, anything of the form x = (c/p)^2.(p-1)^2.n and y = (c/p)^2.n, should work, where p is a factor of c that is greater than 1. Also, anything like that but with x and y swapped. Obviously your p=c should work for any c > 1, as here.

How does this solve the problem? How does your equation solve the problem? Why do you equate y and n? What mathematical reasoning lies behind your code? Please take some time to read or refresh about how to write a good answer. And remember that code-only answers tend to promote cargo cult programming, which is a bad thing.
